# i want react hook cascading select option

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, cascadingdropdown

code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const lookup = {
  "num": [
    { id: '1', text: '1' },
    { id: '2', text: '2' },
    { id: '3', text: '3' },
    { id: '4', text: '4' },
    { id: '5', text: '5' }
  ],
  "en": [
    { id: 'a', text: 'a' },
    { id: 'b', text: 'b' },
    { id: 'c', text: 'c' },
    { id: 'd', text: 'd' },
    { id: 'e', text: 'e' }
  ]
}

const App = ({}) => {
  
  this.setState()

  const [ data ] = useState('num');

  const { data } = this.state;


    const options = lookup[data];
    
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange = {({ target: { value } }) => {this.setState({ data: value })}}>
          <option value="num">Integers</option>
          <option value="en">Alphabets</option>
        </select>
        <hr />
        <select>
          {options.map(a => <option key={a.id} value={a.id}>{a.text}</option>)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 30:11:  Parsing error: Identifier 'data' has already been declared

  28 |   const [ data ] = useState('num');
  29 | 
> 30 |   const { data } = this.state;
     |           ^
  31 | 
  32 | 
  33 |     const options = lookup[data];
```

An error occurred while changing from a class component to a function component. I'm not good at english i want cascading select option A compilation error occurs when running I'm still a beginner, so I don't know what's wrong How can I solve it
I want a function component, not a class component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are converting to a functional component, there's no need to use `this.state`.

The useState hook returns a tuple where the first element is the state and the 2nd one is the setter for that state.

So here in your case you can use like this:

```
const [ data, setData ] = useState('num');
```

Now call the setData from the onChange callback.

```
<select onChange = {({ target: { value } }) => {setData(value);}}>
```

This will update the `data` state and will rerender the component.